# Coordinates format for mapkit

Tags: ios, objective-c

For some reason my format of coordinates do not work in MapKit. For example `LAT 51 18.47387N LONG 000 33.28466W`. Other formats seem to work fine for example `LAT 50.3332 LONG -50.3332`. Could someone explain why this is and how i could fix it. My Lat and Long come from a server and cannot be changed so i was just going to save the value in a `UITextField` and load the map from there. Is there a way to make my coordinates work or a way i can make them translate to a different format in the application?

```
MKPointAnnotation *annonation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D mycordinate;
mycordinate.latitude = [self.myTextField floatValue];
mycordinate.longitude =[self.myTextField1 floatValue];
annonation.coordinate = mycordinate;
[self.mapview addAnnotation:annonation];


MapPin *ann = [[MapPin alloc] init];
ann.title = @"Test";
ann.subtitle = @"test";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapview addAnnotation:ann];
```

Comment: Where do you try to "read" them ?

Comment: hi @Larme i have added the rest of my code that loads the textfields, i read them from a textfield on my storyboard.

Comment: What are exactly the `text` values of the textField?

Comment: there just coordinates in this format  51 18.47387N, 000 33.28466W

Comment: Did you look how `floatValue` works?

Comment: Yes it seems the FloatValue is not the issue just the coordinate format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates seem to be in Degrees (integer) [space] Minutes (float) format.
You need to parse the two numbers and create the decimal degrees as

dDegs = iDegs + dMinutes / 60.0

**Update**
As commentator @Larme points out, a simple way to do this is

```
NSArray *components = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; 
float iDegs = [components[1] floatValue]; // components[0] is "Lat"/"Long"
float dMinutes = [components[2] floatValue];
float dDegs = iDegs + dMinutes / 60.0;
```

However, you'll need to test the final character, as "W" (west) for longitude or "S" (south) for latitude will require you to negate the answer. Something like...

```
if [text hasSuffix:"S"] || [text hasSuffix:"W"] { dDegs = -dDegs; }
```

Comment: How would i go about using this?

Comment: Something like `NSArray *components = text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; float iDegs = [components[1] floatValue]; float dMinutes = [components[2] floatValue];`?

Comment: Thanks, @Larme. I incorporated your hint into the answer - hope you don't mind. Also added test for negatives.

Comment: I don't mind. It was just an hint and you gave a good answer about degree when I didn't know about that.